# Generating a sitemap using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to parse a webpage and create a site map using python. I've written the below piece of code -

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
mypage = "http://example.com/"
page = urllib2.urlopen(mypage)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

all_links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in all_links:
    print link.get('href')
```

The above code prints all the links in `example.com`(external and internal).

- I need to filter out the external links and print only the internal links, I know I can differentiate them using domain name "example.com" and "somethingelse.com" or whatever the name is, but I'm unable to the RE format to get this - or if there is any built in library that helps in achieveing this
- Once I get all the internal links - how do I map them. For instance `"example.com"` has link to `"example.com/page1"` which has link to `"example.com/page3"`. What is the ideal way to create a map for this kind of flow ? I'm looking for a library or logic which shows `"example.com" -> "example.com/page1" -> "example.com/page3"` or something similar

Answer (score 5):

I have written a piece of code for generating sitemap.xml file in python flask frame work

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import datetime

    def registerSiteMaps():
        root = ET.Element('urlset')
        root.attrib['xmlns:xsi']="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        root.attrib['xsi:schemaLocation']="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
        root.attrib['xmlns']="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"

        q = db.result

        for doc in q.results:
            uid = doc['uid']
            site_root = uid.replace('__', '/').replace('_', '-')
            dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y-%m-%d")
            doc = ET.SubElement(root, "url")
            ET.SubElement(doc, "loc").text = "https://www.example.com/"+site_root
            ET.SubElement(doc, "lastmod").text = dt
            ET.SubElement(doc, "changefreq").text = "weekly"
            ET.SubElement(doc, "priority").text = "1.0"

        tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
        tree.write('sitemap.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

For more details, follow this [link](https://www.clickittech.com/developer/create-your-own-sitemap-for-dynamic-content-with-python/)

Comment: I get write() argument must be str, not xml.etree.ElementTree.Element

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, you can use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to parse hostnames and check the domain. Do not use hand rolled regex to do that, it is much easier with a core library like that. See:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
parsed = urlparse(url)
hostname = parsed.hostname`
```

For your second question, your data structure looks like a graph doesn't it? You could use a custom graph data structure with nodes and links between them. Or you could use a graph database made for this purpose. Both of these solutions will be much complex for your needs though. I think it might be better to just use a dictionary data type where key is the page's URL and value is a list of links in that page for example. You can't easily follow links in this case as in a graph but it will still do the trick. You can also keep another set data type for tracking links you have visited.